# CentOS - semanage - Adding Custom Port Fails

Tags: centos, selinux

I recently upgraded one of my application servers to CentOS 6(.2) and was getting it ready for production use when I can across the following issue; Whenever I try to add a custom http port by way of semanage, I keep getting the following error messages:

```
libsemanage.semanage_exec_prog: Child process /sbin/setfiles did not exit cleanly.
libsemanage.semanage_install_active: setfiles returned error code -1.
libsemanage.semanage_exec_prog: Child process /sbin/setfiles did not exit cleanly.
libsemanage.semanage_install_active: setfiles returned error code -1.
/usr/sbin/semanage: Could not commit semanage transaction
```

The command I am trying to run:

```
semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 27960
```

Current kernel:

```
 2.6.32-220.4.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 24 02:13:44 GMT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Current policycoreutils-python:

```
2.0.83-19.18.el6
```

And finally, current selinux settings:

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

Anyone come across this issue before? If so how did you resolve?

Thanks in advance

-- Edit --

I checked /var/log/messages and it looks like semanage is failing due to " kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 1648 (semanage) score 769 or sacrifice child". This is odd because I have an near exact clone (on linode.com) with same cpu/mem specs and the command runs fine.

`free -t -m` on server where semanage keeps failing:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           489         79        410          0          0         11
-/+ buffers/cache:         67        422
Swap:            0          0          0
Total:         489         79        410
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the issue, I forgot to add a swap drive when I implemented my own custom kernel vs the pre-canned kernels. When I added the swap drive back, the command ran fine.

Answer (score 7):

Had a very similar problem on Digital Ocean. Some VM hosts (Digital Ocean, AWS, Rackspace) may NOT have swap space enabled by default, which apparently causes `semanage` to get killed.

On the CentOS 7 VMs that I've played with, `semanage` needed 300 to 400 MB of free RAM before executing the command, to run successfully without getting killed.

Comment: Cool glad this helped. My response has become so Pavlovian with regards to search results on tech topics, if the result isn't part of the SO family, I keep searching until I find one.